# Continuous functions problem commonly seen

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

For all $x,y \in R$
Given $$|f(x) - f(y)|\leq \frac{1}{2} |x-y|$$
Find all $f(x)$ that satisfy the given condition

I have proved continuity and assumed differentiability but I haven’t been able to move past $$|f’(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$$
Could anyone please help with the rest of the steps with proper proof and explanation?

Edit : without assuming differentiability
I have come to this :

WLOG let $f$ be an increasing function and also let $x>y$

Therefore
$$x>y \implies f(x)>f(y)$$
Thus
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = f(x) - f(y)$$

Thus
$$f(x) - f(y) \leq \frac{1}{2} (x-y)$$
This boils down to

$$2f(x) - x \leq 2f(y) - y$$

I am thinking of defining a new function $g(x) = 2f(x) - x$ but don’t know where that will lead to

Comment: In particular, all functions $f(x) = ax$ with $|a| \le 1/2$ do this. And in fact you cannot go further than what you did. This is the best characterization of f you can give, in my opinion. Not sure what you are asking

Comment: I’m asking how to get to $f(x) = ax$.....

Comment: try using the limit definition of the derivative and then use the given part. let me know if i should explain further.

Comment: The function $f(x) = {1 \over 2} |x|$ satisfies the above but is not differentiable. It is not clear what you are asking, please elaborate.

Comment: @justaguy please explain further since I find it a bit vague...sorry :(

Comment: There is no reason to believe that $f$ has to be linear. There are many more functions satisfying this property (called Lipschitz continuity). In fact, they need not even be differentiable. OP, can you specify what you mean by find $f(x)$? And you should mention that you're assuming $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop yes you’re right....I am assuming $f$ to be differentiable.....thank you...I’ll edit it

Comment: I will clarify in an answer post.

Comment: And what are you trying to prove?????

Comment: $f(x) = a \cos(x)$ with $|a| \le 1/2$ also works... @A.Nag

Comment: This is a sloppy question & it wastes everyone's time trying to unravel what you are asking. Are you asking for all differentiable functions satisfying the condition? If so, please edit and fix the question.

Comment: Well can we just agree on the claim that there are infinite functions that satisfy the given?

Comment: We have to agree on that, the problem is how your question is written. Revise it or it will probably be closed soon.

Comment: It is difficult to avoid using expletives at this stage.

Comment: @nicomezi this is exactly how I got the problem so I don’t really know how else to change it without the risk of assuming anything

Comment: The answer is all functions with a Lipschitz constant of ${1 \over 2}$ or less.

Comment: I posted this before your last edit. And copper.hat gave you the answer.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for finally saying something really helpful. So I guess we can agree on all functions with Lipchitz constant $\leq \frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: I hope this gets closed before I get an anurism.

Answer (score 2):

Use the limit definition of the derivative:

$$|f'(x)| = \lim_{h\to0} \left|{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}} \right|= \lim_{(y-x)\to0} \left|{\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}}\right| = \lim_{(y-x)\to0} {\frac{\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|}{\left|y-x\right|}} \leq \frac{1}{2} $$

the last step being possible because of what is given.

I believe the question was changed since I started this answer but if this is what you want, then great, otherwise sorry!

Comment: See this is what I did too and got nowhere and that’s why I gave this problem here.....so sorry but it’s not that helpful :(

Comment: idrk what ur asking but if you are looking for ways to describe these functions look up lipschitz continuous functions

Comment: yes it helped thank you :)